# How to decrypt groovy file created by cim.bat of ATG

Tags: encryption, atg, atg-dynamo

I have recorded execution of CIM.bat after installing ATG. However, I have forgotten to give noencryption flag, so the recorded file will be encrypted with the password I have given. Is there any way to decrypt the encrypted file generated by CIM if we know the password that is used to encrypt the CIM setup apart form rerunning the CIM?

Does ATG provide any API to decrypt these files?

Comment: Hello, This is not a generic question about decryption of a any file. I would like to find out if there is any API in ATG to do this. Please reopen the question.